# How add distinct keys from values containing "(?)" in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, key

In my xsl file I create an index like this:

```
  <xsl:key name="creators" match="dc:creator" use="."/>
```

And then iterate to find unique values of `dc:creator`

```
  <xsl:for-each select="//dc:creator[generate-id() = generate-id(key('creators',.))]">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:for-each>
```

Interestingly of two different values of which one contains "(?)" only this one is sent to the output. E.g. instead of "Boznańska, Olga (1865-1940) (?)" and "Boznańska, Olga (1865-1940)" I am getting  only "Boznańska, Olga (1865-1940) (?)". My `xsltproc -version` gives

```
Using libxml 20901, libxslt 10128 and libexslt 817 
xsltproc was compiled against libxml 20902, 
libxslt 10128 and libexslt 817 libxslt 10128 was compiled against libxml 20902 
libexslt 817 was compiled against libxml 20902
```

Comment: Please provide proper input, complete XSLT, and the relevant expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(sorry, this should go into a comment, but it won't fit, perhaps it will lead to a solution)*

If I try to recreate your situation, using *[How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)*, can only come up with something like this:

Input XML::

```
<root xmlns:dc="dc">
    <dc:creator>Boznańska, Olga (1865-1940)</dc:creator>
    <dc:creator>Test1</dc:creator>
    <dc:creator>Test2</dc:creator>
    <dc:creator>Test2</dc:creator>
    <dc:creator>Boznańska, Olga (1865-1940) (?)</dc:creator>
    <dc:creator>Boznańska, Olga (1865-1940)</dc:creator>
    <dc:creator>Boznańska, Olga (1865-1940) (?)</dc:creator>
    <dc:creator>Boznańska, Olga (1865-1940) (?)</dc:creator>
    <dc:creator>Boznańska, Olga (1865-1940)</dc:creator>
</root>
```

XSLT 1.0 stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:dc="dc"
    xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform'>

    <xsl:key name="creators" match="dc:creator" use="."/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="//dc:creator[generate-id() = generate-id(key('creators',.))]">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XML (kinda) output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>Boznańska, Olga (1865-1940)
Test1
Test2
Boznańska, Olga (1865-1940) (?)
```

In other words, using the information you provided, it "just works". I tried with Xalan, .NET, XsltProc (using libxsl), all with the same result (the latter adding a non-required extra whiteline after the prolog).

So (and that's why this currently is not *really* an answer), can you update your question to give a verifiable example of your present bug?

Comment: Good news! Then it's most probably something else. The input XML is huge and it would not be possible to paste here. I will try to isolate the problem and send the example.

Comment: @helcim, I am not suggesting you paste it here. I am suggesting to create a minimal example that replicates your error. Just the process of doing so may already point you to the issue. Otherwise all we can do is guessing. See [mcve] for more info on how to do this.

Comment: Indeed. I was fooled into a false assumption by  supposedly weird sequence containing a question mark. The culprit was an ill-devised xsl:if which I considered harmless but which prevented all entries to be output in the end. All is fine with the key() function :)